# Double click button to log in with AsyncTask?

Tags: android

So lets say the user enters the right credentials and they click the button to sign in, i have to click it twice to sign in. i think its because i declare it at the beginning of my AsyncTask but i am not to sure.

How i want it to work: user enters correct credentials, they click the button, the AsyncTask calls my server and makes sure the credentials are correct and it sets the variable to be false (so i know the log in worked) and then the activity starts.

AsyncTask code:

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <String,Void,String> {
Context ctx;

public static boolean LOGIN_FAILED = true;

public static String Account;

BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
//removed extra code here for the question. This is where i get result 
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if(result.equals("Login failed...")){
        //If there email or password didn't match up in the DB then they couldn't log in.
        LOGIN_FAILED = true;
    }else{
        LOGIN_FAILED = false;

        if (result.equals("Welcome: Buyer")){
            Account = "Buyer";
        }else if(result.equals("Welcome: Seller")){
            Account = "Seller";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Button code (i call this method when the button is clicked):

```
public void startActivity() {
    //If the user gets the credentials right when they sign in then i start the activity.
    if (BackgroundTask.LOGIN_FAILED == false) {
        if (BackgroundTask.Account.equals("Buyer")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BuyerHomePage.class));

        } else if (BackgroundTask.Account.equals("Seller")) {

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SellerHomePage.class));

        }

    }else if(BackgroundTask.LOGIN_FAILED == true){

        //A TOAST shows up (because the user couldn't connect) saying they messed up there email or password.
        Toast.makeText(SignInForm.this, "Email or password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the code you shared, there is nowhere you are calling your AsyncTask.

Assumptions: assuming the async is called in startActivity(). Then if as soon as you call async task, you check for value of `BackgroundTask.LOGIN_FAILED`

....
That is wrong approach. Async will happen in background, so before the task is completed your code makes a check for `BackgroundTask.LOGIN_FAILED`.
Correct approach is to start your activity on completion of `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 0):

In your button click you're starting activities, but in your description you indicate you make a call to a server. Which one is correct? Why would you start an activity on button click before you have validated the credentials?

Also, assuming your service makes an asynchronous call to validate the credentials, you don't need an async task to call into it, the service should return immediately from that "validate credentials" call from the activity and, once it has validated the credentials, it should call back into your activity via a callback method.

Comment: Sorry when i click the button i call my server and checks to see if the email and password entered match the email and password in the DB.

Comment: Could you share the code where you start the async task?

Comment: how should i do that?